# How can I use a SQL UPDATE statement to add 1 year to a DATETIME column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add 1 year to a datetime-type column in every single row in a table. Adding using an UPDATE statement is easy for numeric types. ex:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET NUMBERCOLUMN = NUMBERCOLUMN + 1
```

I'd like to do the same thing with a DATETIME-type...

```
UPDATE Procrastination SET DropDeadDueDate = DropDeadDueDate + ?
```

...but I'm not sure what value to use. Is there a numeric value I could use that means "1 year"? Or is there a DATEADD function or similar in SQL Server?

ADDITIONAL QUESTION

I would like to do this for not one field, but for every field in the database of data type 'datetime'.  Is there an easy way to select all fields of type 'datetime' and perform an update of adding x amount of years?  I am new to sql so please be gentle...

Comment: @shahkalpesh - Perhaps I should have. I have no doubt I *could* have found the answer on my own. But since StackOverflow seems to be aspiring to be a repository of all programming knowledge, and this question hadn't been asked yet, I figured "why not?".

Comment: @Joshua, see my comment to Kev under my answer. When I look at your question, it seems you have already answered that in part by saying DATEADD. If people ask questions, they could easily find in books online - this will become a link exchange rather than real problems/solutions - which one can't find in MSDN/Books online/internet. Just my opinion, nothing personal. Peace :)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There is in fact a DATEADD statement in T-SQL, you can find it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

```
UPDATE Procrastination SET DropDeadDueDate = DATEADD(yyyy,1,DropDeadDueDate)
```

EDIT: You could use *year*, *yy*, or *yyyy* for the first argument of DATEADD.

Comment: I want to do same thing in phpmyadmin but it says '#1305 - FUNCTION [table_name].ADD_DATE does not exist '

Answer (score 9):

It could be done with a DATEADD() function like this:

```
UPDATE Procrastination SET DropDeadDueDate = DATEADD(yy, 1, DropDeadDueDate)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE Procrastination SET DropDeadDueDate = DATEADD(year, 1, DropDeadDueDate)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Comment: @Bob: it should be DATEADD(year, 1, DropDeadDueDate)

Comment: Whoops, thanks, tried typing it out too fast, not fast enough though.

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server has a DATEADD function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258267(SQL.80).aspx

Answer (score 4):

The [DateAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258267(SQL.80).aspx) function should do what you want.

```
UPDATE Procrastination SET DropDeadDueDate = DateAdd(yy, 1, DropDeadDueDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE Procrastination SET DropDeadDueDate =

DATEADD(yy, 1, DropDeadDueDate)`

ref: http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/da-db_5.htm

Comment: whilst the link is useful, wouldn't have a more recent MSDN link have been more helpful rather than a SQL7 one?  The only reason I ask is that you criticised the OP for NOT researching the answer him/herself??

Comment: @Kev:I am not criticizing :) Yes, the link is older but things haven't changed for that function, as far as I know. My idea is that questions/answers should be for things, one wouldn't find easily in documentation/MSDN. Hope that justifies my comments.