# Is use of <u>underline</u> deprecated and non validated?

Tags: html, xhtml, w3c

Is use of underline deprecated and non validated?

Comment: No offense, but it would have been just as easy to check the html/xhtml specs at w3.org and see the answer to your question as it was to ask it here.

Comment: Too bad you asked a Yes-No question. Regardless, it's interesting to ask/know the *why*: HTML is supposed to represent markup. Styling is supposed to be done by CSS. The W3 HTML guys realized that later and decided to deprecate style-specific elements from HTML. Just separation of responsiblity, which is a Good Thing.

Comment: As has been said more times than I can think... Just because you can find the answer to a question on another site does not mean you shouldn't ask it here! The more questions that are asked/answered here the less other places you will ever have to visit.

Comment: Can we please leave comments when we downvote? The question is valid, please let the user know why you feel it deserved a vote against it. Is it a duplicate? Do you feel that it's not detailed enough? The poster can't correct their behavior if there's no indication as to what they did "wrong".

Comment: Why i asked it because many WYSIWYG editor still use "U" button to make text underline

Comment: @Robin - Really? I've been chastised for asking questions that I could have looked up the answer to on my own. ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951982 ). I guess the community hasn't come to a consensus as to whether this is a good idea. Ah well.

Comment: @Joshua: The community might not but the founders certainly have.

Comment: @Jitendra: ask/mention/complain it to the authors of the editor in question.

Comment: @Jitendra - Most of the WYSIWYG HTML editors I've used aren't exactly what you'd call standards compliant :) The 'U' button is there to make Microsoft Word users feel more at home.

Comment: @Joshua et al: Maybe the questioner couldn't find what he was looking for at W3. I suspect that for a high percentage of the questions asked on sites like this, the answer is available SOMEWHERE on the web. The problem is that the asker doesn't know where to look or doesn't understand what he finds there. If the rule is that no one is allowed to ask a question that anyone else knows the answer to, then the only questions left are those that no one can answer, which would make sites like this pretty useless.

Comment: RE the close: While it is true that this question HAS generated a lot of discussion and opinion, as written it called for a simple yes or no answer: is the tag deprecated or not? :-)

Comment: [HTML5 return of <u> (semantic) element](http://html5doctor.com/u-element/)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's deprecated in HTML 4 http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/graphics.html#edef-U so won't validate.

Use styles instead. Maybe a `<span>` tag. Although, if you want the thing you're trying to add an underline to, to be emphasized without styles enabled. Use an `<em>` tag and use CSS to give it an underline.

Comment: yey nothing like more code to write. Why would any logical person replace <u></u> with <span style="text-decoration:underline;></span>
7 chars vs 47. Plain stupid. Im sticking with <u> even though I can't say I really ever use it.

Comment: Because logical people use classes or css overrides over inline styles, and understand the significance of keeping the structure of the document separate from the formatting of the document.

Comment: Adding a <span> tag is little different from adding a <u> tag. Sure CSS is much more powerful, but when actually writing HTML by hand, <u> can often be a heck of a lot simpler. It should not have been deprecated.

Comment: @JoelMueller: If one wishes to underline a header, that should be done using styles rather than an inline `<u>` tag.  On the other hand, in something like a quiz which instructs people to identify the part of speech of each underlined word, the use of underlining would be a semantic rather than presentation issue.  Any other visual representation would be semantically wrong unless the human-readable instructions were changed appropriately.

Comment: @supercat but using an underline would be bad for accessibility as this is the default behaviour from a browser for an anchor. This answer explains it in more detail: http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/18088

Answer (score 21):

Yes, it's deprecated. Use styles instead. Note also that underlined text can be confusing, as it resembles the default styling of links, and might frustrate some users.

If you wanted, you could even repurpose another HTML element, like `em`:

**CSS:**

```css
em {
  font-style: normal;         /* Removes italics */
  text-decoration: underline; /* Makes underline */
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<p>I like to <em>underline</em> words.</p>
```

Comment: but It takes more character than <u>

Comment: @Jitrenda: This makes no sense :) First ask yourself why you need the underline? Just to *emphasize* text? If so, then you can also just grab `<em>` and use CSS to underline it by default.

Comment: I would do what BalusC suggests, emphasize the text with em and then choose how it is emphasized with a stylesheet. Rather than have a style class called underline.

Comment: Replacing `<u>` with a class called "underline" is a step backwards. But I agree about confusing underlined text with links - IMO you shouldn't underline text at all on web pages apart from links or headings (in which case, you'd attach the CSS to a heading tag).

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat I'm not encouraging the example, only showing how CSS handles itself as the alternative to the dreadful **u**.

Comment: @BalusC I think this does make fair sense. You may have a much more common case for <em> standard in posts on some sites. Now whether or not that extra byte matters alot,...well.. not.

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas Instead why not use the <i> for your custom word style in css, now that italics have moved on to <em>? These days with HTML5 <i> is more of a dialogue cue anyway. Of course, then again browsers will probably always understand both <u> and <i> anyway.

Comment: @BalusC: In cases where the *human-readable text of a document* makes mention of things being underlined, the semantics of the `<u>` tag were much more suitable than `<em>`.

Answer (score 8):

<rant>

General comment on "semantics versus style": While there is certainly truth to this, it is a lesson that some people have way way overlearned.

In real life, many people use italics for emphasis. Sure, I could create a CSS style of "span.emphasized { font-style: italic;}", and then instead of putting "<i></i>" around the emphasized text, put "<span class='emphasized'></span>". And exactly what does that gain, besides a lot of extra typing?

Further, there are a million reasons why I might want to put a piece of text in, say, italics. Perhaps it is the title of a book; perhaps I want to emphasize it; perhaps I am using the convention of italicizing foreign words; etc. If I have 10 words in a document that are italicized for 9 different reasons, the pedantic answer is that I should create 9 different CSS style entries to describe all these reasons. Personally, I almost never do this, because it gains nothing. Yes, theoretically I might decide that book titles should be in a cursive font instead of italicized or some such. In practice, the probability that this will happen is pretty close to zero, and if it did, and I have two such book titles in my document, I can just change it twice. Theoretically someone might want to scan my text with a program that looks for book titles. But in practice, unless we have arranged this in advance and we have agreed on the CSS class names, there is no way they are going to do this.

I'm not saying CSS is useless. Quite the contrary. When I have a semantic object that is repeated many times in my text, and which has no "natural", widely-recognized style, it then becomes quite plausible to suppose that as I continue to work on the document I may want to change the style. In that case it is much easier to change a single CSS entry than to change a hundred instances. Or I may want to use a different style in different situations, like put warning messages in red when displaying on the screen but put them in bold when printing a black-and-white document.

For example, I routinely use CSS for quote citations because I often change my mind about italicizing, indenting, and font size. I never use CSS for text that I want italicized for emphasis because I know it is extremely unlikely that I will ever want to render this as anything other than italics.

My point is, I don't care that some pedant said "This is a rule that you must always obey. You ask why you must obey it? But I just told you! Because it's a rule!" I use tools and techniques that are useful in the present application. (And yes, yes, there are lots of rules of thumb that are valid 99% of the time and aren't worth thinking about until the rare exception turns up.)

</rant>

Comment: The comment "natural, widely-recognized style" in regards to the "world" wide web doesn't really work. What happens when you make chinese text italic? The internet gives us global coverage, this is something you always need to consider unless you know exactly what your entire target audience is.

Comment: @Robin: Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not aware of any way to just flip a switch and turn English text into Chinese. If someone translates a document I've written into Chinese, I presume they'll translate the italics into some corresponding Chinese method of indicating emphasis. If you're thinking of a Babelfish translation, (a) given the crudeness of machine translations, inadequate handling of italics is the least of your worries; and in any case (b) it would surely be easier to deal with standard &lt;i&gt; tags then a custom-designed CSS class.

Comment: Use of `<em>` is better than `<i>` in cases where the method of emphasis should depend upon how the text is being rendered.  For example, if a block of text is set in a script font, trying to use italics to emphasize a word would be less effective than e.g. showing that word in a contrasting color.  On the other hand, there are some cases where using anything other than italic text would be semantically wrong, and substitutes should only be used if there is literally no alternative (e.g. rendering text on a VT100 terminal).

Comment: Additional comment 12 years later: When you do use CSS classes, 99% of the time I'd recommend giving them names that describe the semantics and not the presentation, and then using them where that semantics makes sense. Like, I worked on a web site where the original developer created a class ".red {color: red}". Why? It appeared to be used primarily for error messages. So why not call it "error"? Then if later you decided that error messages should be in purple instead of red, you don't have the confusing situation of saying "class=red" and the text turns up purple. ...

Comment: ... Furthermore, if you have some other reason to make text red, say, some section headings, it is a bad idea to use the same CSS class for both error messages and section headings just because in your first draft you decide to make them both red. What if later you decide that error messages should indeed be red but section headings should be in a larger font and bold? Now you have to find every instance of "class=red", figure out which it is, and change the section headings to some other class.

Answer (score 6):

**The `<u>` tag has been deprecated in favor of stylesheets.**

Most browsers will continue to recognize it for a long time to come, simply out of need to be backwards compatible with the content already out there. But if you want to by XHTML compliant, you should avoid using it.,

You can read some more about [deprecated HTML tags here](http://www.codehelp.co.uk/html/deprecated.html).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it was deprecated in HTML 4. However, you can just use the following css.

```
span.underline { text-decoration: underline; }
```

However, the underline class name is not semantic. You may want to replace it with a class name that describes the content you need underlined.

Answer (score 1):

The  tag is deprecated but not obsolete. The reason it's not obsolete is to allow browsers to support the  element for backward compatibility.

The  tag is not defined in the **xhtml1-strict.dtd** but it's available under **xhtml1-frameset.dtd** and **xhtml1-transitional.dtd**. It's declaration are as follows (not on Strict DTD):

```
<!ELEMENT u %Inline;>   <!-- underline -->
<!ATTLIST u %attrs;>
```

This is to allow backward compatibility with browsers.

**Do not** use the  tag as "**This tag has been deprecated in favor of style sheets**". It may soon become obsolete. Rather use stylesheet, e.g.

```
/** Underlining an anchor tag in CSS **/
a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated: yes.
Validated: ?  I guess that depends on what you are using to validate it.

http://www.codehelp.co.uk/html/deprecated.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your question with both XHTML and HTML. the U tag is definitely deprecated in xhtml-strict. I think it may still be OK in HTML-4-Transitional. As other people have said, use styles instead. With good name they give more semantics to your docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the latest version of HTML or XHTML then yes it's deprecated.
Regardless, in general you want to avoid underlining anything that isn't a link, as it can make things more confusing for the user.